# How do you upsert to an array of objects by multiple object IDs in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to use an array of object IDs to update objects found in a MongoDB array. The behavior I am seeing is that the 'old' elements are not being pulled and the updated elements are still being pushed, making the array longer.

For context, I have a 'response' collection with a 'response_elements' property that is an array of response element objects. I must be able to upsert on the array of response_elements.

Here is my code:

```
await ResponseModel.findOneAndUpdate({ id: updatedResponse.id }, {
  $pull: {
    response_elements: {
      id: { $in: elementIdsToUpdate },
    },
  },
}, { upsert: false, multi: true });

await ResponseModel.findOneAndUpdate({ id: updatedResponse.id }, {
  $push: { response_elements: { $each: response_elements } },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want with one query to remove some elements, and add some others, you can do it like bellow.

Query

- filter to remove the elements [0,2]
- concat to add the elements [5,6,7]

*pipeline update required MongoDB >= 4.2
*if you know that the elements are unique you can also use `$setDifference` instead of `$filter`

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6251a8aef7e3c64c6511e16f)

```js
update({},
[{"$set": 
   {"response_elements": 
     {"$concatArrays": 
       [{"$filter": 
          {"input": "$response_elements",
           "cond": {"$not": [{"$in": ["$$this", [0, 2]]}]}}},
        [5, 6, 7]]}}}])
```